# Can't execute a MySQL stored procedure from JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Im trying to connect to the mariadb server in jdbc and call my stored procedure but im getting this error.
Ive also tried:

'''GRANT all ON mysql.proc TO 'Gruppe18'@'i3ED6FBF0.versanet.det';'''

but in mysql i got access denied error.

And the server is from university so I dont have full access on it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v27Kx.jpg)

Comment: *"im getting this error"* What error might that be? --- Can you run the stored procedure directly yourself, i.e. not using Java/JDBC?

Comment: yes i can run the stored procedure in mysql and it works, i just upload a photo of the error.

Comment: This is a great example of the need for including relevant information, like the code causing the problem. There's no way we could have helped without actually seeing the code. Next time, please include the code as text, not as an image. I'm going to leave the down-vote, because this question is of no use to others. They won't ever find it, since it doesn't include any code or error message in text form that would allow a search to locate the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image shows that you're using named parameters, which means that the JDBC driver needs to query the meta-data of the stored procedure to learn what those parameters are.

Your user is not authorized to query that meta-data.

*Solution:* Use positional parameters.